# Image wrapper by img tag with external url

Tags: media

I want to customize image field so as I am able to add external url and display in node without save locally.

The image is already online to another site. For example www.example.com/imageurl.jpg. The only thing I want to do is to wrap this on a drupal field like this `<img src="www.example.com/imageurl.jpg"/>`

Is there any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module to get external images via their URL and show it in the node page.

By saving locally if you mean 'locally' in the server that is running Drupal then it doesn't do that. To achieve it you will need a separate server like `Amazon S3` to store your images alone.

Comment: I updated my question